# How can I grab next Word after Regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to grab the Word from a text file AFTER the IP regex match ($2):

fileName.txt:

IP hostname blah blah blah...

blah blah..

IP hostname blah blah blah...
.
.
.

I want the hostnames for each instance of the IP (which I found with grep regex and stored it in $var). I want to use found hostnames to set to $host and print them out onto a text file with the IPs (which are already done).

I have tried multiple methods from online answers but they all printed blanks.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think a regex is the right tool for this job?

Comment: I used regex to find IP address: var=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' test_amy_hostrun.txt) but I want to use grep, awk, or sed to get the hostname from the same file I got the IP address and set it to a variable called host.

Comment: How does your desired output differ from the direct output of `grep` with your regex, if you omit the `-o` option?

Comment: BTW, you might consider using `grep -E`, aka `egrep`, which would stop you from needing to backslash-escape the `{`s and `}`s in your regex (which is actually a GNU extension, to make ERE constructs available in BRE; a `grep` which implements no more than the standard requires won't have such support) and let you use proper ERE syntax.

Comment: Edit your question to provide concrete, testable sample input and expected output. `blah blah blah`s don't help us understand your problem. Whatever the details of your problem are, the right solution will be a brief, clear, simple, portable awk script.

Answer (score 1):

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for guidance on how best to read from a stream.

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ important, not /bin/sh

while read -r -a words; do
    # put the array words into $1, $2, $3, etc.
    set -- "${words[@]}"

    # put $1 -- the first word -- into the variable named "ip"
    ip=$1

    # remove $1, leaving only hostnames in $1, $2, etc
    shift

    echo "IP address $ip has the following hostnames:"
    for hostname; do # by default, a for loop iterates over $@
      echo "- ${hostname}"
    done
done < <(grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' test_amy_hostrun.txt)
```

Comment: Your comments always help peel back the veil of confusion... So much of the very basics of scripting are swept under the rug in most self-styled tutorials and references. It is nice to see it clearly laid out, regardless how many times it is reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk  '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{print $1, $2}'
```

will give you IP hostname for the lines starting with the matching regex.

if your awk doesn't support regex interval you need the add --re-interval option.

Comment: No, gawk is the only awk that you DO need `--re-interval` for. That is a gawk-specific option that was required in older gawks to enable RE intervals. In newer gawks it's enabled by default.

Comment: There are several awks that don't support regex intervals and for all of them adding `--re-interval` will either do nothing or give you a syntax error. That option ONLY applies to older versions of gawk.